# fuse.js as a dependency in an aurelia app

Tags: node.js, aurelia, fuse.js

I've been trying, without success, to add `fuse.js` as a dependency to my aurelia-based app.

The app was initialized with the `au` tool, and uses TypeScript as the main language.

In `aurelia_project/aurelia.json`, I've tried adding the dependency in the following formats, under `build.bundles[vendor-bundle].dependencies`:

```
"fuse.js"

{
  "name": "fuse.js",
  "path": "../node_modules/fuse.js/dist/fuse"
}

{
  "name": "fuse.js",
  "path": "../node_modules/fuse.js/dist/",
  "main": "fuse"
}
```

Neither has given me the library available at runtime (always `undefined` when imported by `import * as Fuse from 'fuse.js';`, and the two first have given me errors when building.

**How can I add `fuse.js` as a dependency to an aurelia app?**

Answer (score 1):

I use fuse.js in my app as a value converter, my structure is webpack and dotnet core,

1. npm install fuse.js --save
2. add fuse.js in my vendor part of webpack.config.vendor file
3. npm install @types/fuse
4. I created a value converter like :

   ```
   import { FuseOptions } from 'fuse.js';
   import * as Fuse from 'fuse.js';

   export class FuseValueConverter {

   toView(value: Array<any>, options: FuseOptions, criteria: string) {
      console.log(value);

      if (!options || !criteria)
          return value || [];

      const fuse = new Fuse(value, options);

      return fuse.search(criteria);
      }
   }
   ```

and then I caleed it in my view models just like any other value converter in Aurelia

Answer (score 0):

Is it not that aurelia does not use extension (.js in your case) when importing? 
Your json file is also incorrectly formatted.

Comment: As far as I can understand, the `.js` in the `"name"` shouldn't matter, and it doesn't work with `"name": "fuse"` either. 
What I included in the question is not intended as a well formatted json file - it's just the different parts i tried in the dependency array in my `aurelia.json`

Comment: I see. I am assuming you have already installed it as well: npm install  fuse.js or npm install --save fuse.js

Comment: Yup, `npm install fuse.js`

Comment: And you can locate it from the node_modules folder? Can you try to import the node_module path instead of 'fuse.js' see if it does not give you undefine?

Comment: Jup, fuse is properly installed in `node_modules` and the typescript linter locates it just fine. Importing by path doesn't work, as the path isn't available when opening the website from a browser.

Comment: Not sure whether it would help you with this link: https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/pull/124 but some have found some work around. Although this may not be related since you are using aurelia.

Comment: yeah it is related, changing the dist file to an anonymous module works. another way is to use as a global object (load it in the prepend section before requirejs).

Comment: @RabahG wouldn't changing the dist file be impractical, as it would change every time the dependency is updated, and would require manual patching for anyone pulling my repo? Could you expand on the other way, using a global? I don't understand what you mean by "load it in the prepend section before requirejs)

Comment: @totokaka it isn't practical to change the dist file sure. as for the global approach just put "node_modules/fuse.js/dist/fuse.js" in the "prepend" section of the bundle in aurelia.json: https://gist.github.com/arabsight/d86bbcea269b74de5844331a85eca22d. this way you can assess it globally (new Fuse()) without importing anything.

Comment: @RabahG Using the `prepend` section in `aurelia.json` worked. Would you like to write a proper answer, so I can accept it as the correct one?